# How to apply limit on sequlize table rows number?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js, limit

I want to apply limit on Sequelize table declaration.
This would actually limit the rows total of the table to 1 by forbidding to add more rows into it.
How can I achieve this in the table model definition?

Comment: Are you asking to limit total number of rows of a table to 1? Why would you want that restriction? What kind of data are you storing?

Comment: @XavierGarnier yes I have to add only once license id in first row and restrict user to add more row manually or through query

Comment: Could you define your database structure then? Like the tables you currently have, at least license and user I believe. It would be easier to help find the best possible way.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that it is a good idea to use database table with only one row possible.

But a technical solution could be to use a default primary key (e.g. `id: 1`).
This primary key won't be auto increment or anything but a static default value like integer `1`.
So that you could not add any other rows than the very first one, as a primary key is unique and it's value is always equals to `1`. So you would only be able to update or read its value, if that's why you're trying to achieve.

But again this sounds like an anti-SQL thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 'limit' option in sequelize:

```
findAll({
    limit: 2,
    where: { YOUR QUERY }
)}
```

Comment: I believe (s)he wants to limit the number of rows possible in that table, not the size of the select query.

Comment: exactly I want to limit rows

Answer (score 0):

If you want to limit records, why don't do this in the controller / service / business logic part?

Before creating a record, you can `findAll` or `count` the records/rows what the current user have and apply your rule

Or even, you can add a `beforeCreate` hook if apply...